# How to implement SAML2.0 SSO in Windows forms C# Dot Net

Tags: c#, .net, saml, saml-2.0, windowsformsintegration

I have to implement the SAML 2.0 SSO In windows forms but mostly suggestable for Web only but we can able to do by using embed the web Browser tool used in windows forms but redirect is not triggering.

How to redirect from recipient URL to IDP to Authentication URL(Microsoft) in Windows forms c#.Net?